# what would cause a bathroom sink connector hose to pop off

Tags: plumbing, water, water-heater, water-pressure, hot-water

Around 7 am this morning I woke up to my bathroom sink spewing water from underneath. The hot water feed was disconnected including the water shut off valve and spewing burning hot water into my bathroom. I am curious to know what would cause this to happen, and what I can do to prevent it from happening again? We live in a rental townhome built about 3 years ago, although since it is a college construction I wouldn't doubt that they cut corners with things like plumbing. Never had any problems really with the water, other than the pressure from that sink being fairly *low*. help? I know I don't know many plumbing technical terms so I am including a (poor) picture of the plumbing. [image][image]
** update! I remembered that yesterday our power went off for like two minutes. This happens every now and then, and we usually have to go and flip the breaker. Could this ahve somehting ot do with it?

Comment: Can you get a better picture of the end of the pipe coming out of the wall? And of the corresponding side of the shutoff valve?

Comment: I'm currently out of the house and the plumber may have already come by the time I get home but I will try to ask my roommates. I've had so many problems with our management doing a half job on everything so that's why I want to get a second opinion.

Comment: I love that you stopped to take a photo as water was filling up your house. :P Looks like a faulty/improper PEX connection.

Comment: Agree with isher.

Answer (score 1):

Since those flex connectors are pretty cheap, I'd just buy a new one rather than figure out whether the existing one has lost tension at the spring connection or just got dirty/greasy enough to lose hold.

Of course, make sure the end of the source pipe is clean, and if it looks worn or damaged, cut a half-inch or so off before reconnecting.

Comment: so the connector just needs to be replaced? I was worried that there was something weird going on with the water pressure but that is a much easier problem to fix